# Page_Validators is not defined

Tags: .net, asp.net, routes

i am using asp.net routing

when using ValidatorEnable function in javascript  i got this error 'Page_Validators is not defined'
how to solve this?

i am using this code in my global.asax file

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

I solved it by executing the code that uses Page_Validators from the $(document).ready event.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone working with old code bases and hitting this all these years later.

You have little control over `Page_Validators` being defined. It's done by the Framework, so you're almost certainly calling one of the validator methods before `WebUIValidation.js` has had a chance to finish defining it.

In my case it was a very stupid thing: `$(document).ready(myPageJs.Init())`.

Amateur mistake, the () syntax means Init will execute right away, which in turn calls `ValidatorEnable` which was yet to be defined.

The fix being: `$(document).ready(myPageJs.Init)`.

`Init` is now actually deferred and all is well.